# Creating TAR file reading standard output

Tags: backup, gzip, mysql, tar, mysql-backup

I'm trying to get into tar file the stdout generated from Mysqldump:

```
mdm@deb606:~$ mysqldump --opt test1 -u root -ppassword | tar -czf  example.tar.gz
```

doesn't work.

At the moment I've temporary solved using:

```
mdm@deb606:~$ mysqldump --opt test1 -u root -ppassword | gzip -f > example.gz
```

Is it possible do the the same using also tar or bzip2?

Comment: What advantage is there to making it a `.tar`? It'd be only one file anyway.

Comment: Sure, one file only, but using tar i have chance to choose different kind of compression and other options, specially if my DB become large

Comment: still pointless you can pipe `mysqldump` output to whatever you want, `bzip2`, `xz`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that it's possible to pipe directly into `tar` (in general, that doesn't make a lot of sense), however the `bzip2` command will accept `-` to mean to read from stdin, i.e.:

```
mdm@deb606:~$ mysqldump --opt test1 -u root -ppassword | bzip2 - > example.bz2
```